# c# Rebus - Message not being sent to RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, rebus

I'm trying to publish an event from one API and subscribe to this event from multiple other API's.
I'm trying to accomplish this using Rebus, RabbitMQ and .NET 5.

No matter what I do, the message does not seem to be sent to the queue at all.

my code looks like this

**Sending API**

Startup.cs - ConfigureServices

```
        services.AddRebus(configure => configure
            .Logging(x => x.Serilog())
            .Transport(x => x.UseRabbitMq("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672", "Bus.Users"))
            .Routing(x => x.TypeBased()
                .Map<UserUpdatedEvent>("Bus.Users")));
```

Startup.cs - Configure

```
            app.ApplicationServices.UseRebus();
```

Code that triggers the publish:

```
                var userUpdatedEvent = new UserUpdatedEvent
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                ProfileImageId = user.ProfileImageUuid,
                ProfileImageUrl = user.ProfileImageUrl
            };

            await _bus.Publish(userUpdatedEvent);
```

This code gets triggered everytime, though I never see a message in the queue or error queue in rabbitMQ management.

I've been trying to fix this issue for quite some time now but can't seem to find any solution.
Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Not an answer as such, and I don't know how Rebus works with Rabbit. But in RabbitMQ messages are published to an exchange, and from the exchange forwarded to one or more queues depending on the bindings, exchange types, and routing keys. Do you have both exchanges, queues, and bindings in your rabbitMQ? Do you need to set this up yourself, or does Rebus do this for you?

Comment: Hmm good question. I've changed the setup to 2 channels:
* Bus.Users.Sender
* Bus.Users

Now when I try to send something I see a message appear in the error queue:

`System.AggregateException: 1 unhandled exceptions (Message with ID 67243577-100a-4571-ab96-b4ece16661f7 and type ServiceA.Contracts.Users.UserUpdatedEvent, ServiceA.Contracts.Users could not be dispatched to any handlers (and will not be retried under the default fail-fast settings))`  while I do have a handler in a second project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part

```cs
.Routing(x => x.TypeBased()
                .Map<UserUpdatedEvent>("Bus.Users"))
```

tells Rebus that you want messages of type `UserUpdatedEvent` to be routed to the queue "Bus.Users", so that when you

```cs
await bus.Send(new UserUpdatedEvent(...));
```

the message will be put into the queue "Bus.Users".

It's a simple [point-to-point channel](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/PointToPointChannel.html), where a sender sends a message directly to the recipient's input queue.

That's probably not what you want in this case, since the message is an event. You usually use point-to-point channels for commands, e.g. `UpdateUserCommand` instructing the recipient to update the user.

On the other hand, when you

```cs
await bus.Publish(new UserUpdatedEvent(...));
```

Rebus will generate a topic out of the event type - in your case, it'll be called something like "Messages.UserUpdatedEvent, UserUpdatedEvent", because Rebus defaults to use the short, assembly-qualified type name of the type being published - and publish the event to that topic.

To be able to receive events published to a topic, someone needs to subscribe to it. In your case, you'd simply let your subscriber

```cs
await bus.Subscribe<UserUpdatedEvent>();
```

and then it will start receiving the events. This is a [publish-subscribe channel](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/PublishSubscribeChannel.html), which is handy for distributing events to 0..n subscribers.

I hope that made sense